# Got an issue unit testing with NUnit and an asp.net class that inherits

Tags: c#, .net

First sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

I work on an Asp.Net application with a homemade framework by my company.

I have an issue when I start unit tests with NUnit framework. I want to test methods that are in a class who inherits from an other but I have many errors before started any tests :

> NUnit Adapter 3.12.0.0: Test execution started
>   Running all tests in C:\PRIV\Projects\WebSite0\test\bin\Debug\test.dll
>      NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
>   SetUp failed for test fixture test.Class1
>   System.InvalidOperationException : Aucune implémentation fournie pour ExecEnv
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Global.ExecEnv.get_Implementation() dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbcommon\Global\ExecEnv.cs:ligne 38
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.TraceLog.TraceBase.GetObjectFromStorage() dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbcommon\TraceLog\TraceBase.cs:ligne 37
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Toolkit.DocReflectionToolkit.GetDocumentation(Assembly asm) dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbcommon\Toolkit\DocReflectionToolkit.cs:ligne 115
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Toolkit.DocReflectionToolkit.GetDocumentation(Type type) dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbcommon\Toolkit\DocReflectionToolkit.cs:ligne 46
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Navigation.ReflexiveSteps.Reflection.ReflexiveActionProviderBase.SetupSignature(PublicStepSignature Signature) dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbwebapplication4\Navigation\ReflexiveSteps\Reflection\ReflexiveActionProviderBase.cs:ligne 371
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Navigation.ReflexiveSteps.PageStep..ctor() dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbwebapplication4\Navigation\ReflexiveSteps\Steps\PageStep.cs:ligne 27
>      à CDM.DevbCommon.Navigation.ReflexiveSteps.ObjectPageStep`1..ctor() dans d:\BuildAreas\mk_build\DEVBCOMMON\V5.210\PROJECTS\devbwebapplication4\Navigation\ReflexiveSteps\Steps\ObjectPageStep.cs:ligne 27
>      à CDM.WebSite0.Commands.EmptyPage..ctor()
>      à test.Class1..ctor() dans C:\PRIV\Projects\WebSite0\test\Class1.cs:ligne 17
>   NUnit Adapter 3.12.0.0: Test execution complete

When I hide the inheritance, the unit test works normally without problems.
But with the inheritance, I receive a `System.InvalidOperationException`

Here the unit test class :

```
namespace test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1 
    {
        private readonly EmptyPage vm = new EmptyPage();

        [Test]
        public void TestAddition()
        {
            double actAddNumberResult = vm.AddNumber(5, 7);
            Assert.That(actAddNumberResult, Is.EqualTo(12) );
        }
```

And here the class to test :

```
 public class EmptyPage : ObjectPageStep<EmptyPageViewModel>
    {

        public void Prepare()
        {
        }

        public double AddNumber(double nombre1, double nombre2)
        {
            return nombre1 + nombre2;
        }
```

I tried with XUnit and I have the same problem.

Any idea?

Comment: why does your class derive from `ObjectPageStep`?

Comment: Please translate exception message ("Aucune implémentation fournie pour ExecEnv à ") to English

Comment: Why does your test derive from the same class as the class under test??

Comment: @AleksAndreev, in english : "No implementation for ExecEnv at "   / It was just a test under the class test, i tried to derive just to see what appends but i have the same issue with or without /  my class derive from ObjectPageStep because the homemade framework of my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what is the problem.
From the start, i forgot to tell you but the class to test was Internal access.
I changed to public to make it visible.
i changed it again to Internal and add in Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestClass")]`

Now it works, thank you guys for your Help